# How to display Arraylist objects in table format in Android

Tags: android, arraylist, tablelayout

I have an Arraylist. Employee object contains EmpId, EmpName, Position, ManagerName.

I want to poulate arraylist in a table format with EmpId, EmpName, Position and ManagerName as columns.

I have used ListView with ArrayAdapter but i am getting only rows, I want to display Arraylist as a table.

Please help me, which layout I have to use, and how to display on UI. If possible please share some sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `ListViews` you can define style and borders for your list items and rows, to give it a table look and for headers of your Arraylist you can AddHeaderView to your ListView or include your List layout at the top of your List , so it will look like a table

Comment: Thanks for the reply Arash. Can you please share some example code how to implement this.

Comment: I have added the headerView to my list as below:

empList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.empSearchList);  
View header = View.inflate(this, R.layout.employee_header, null);
empList.addHeaderView(header);

But when I click on header, I am getting an error. How to set header nonclickable

Comment: instead of addHeaderView(header) use addHeaderView(header, null, false); use this parameters to add your HeaderView, third parameter will disable it's onClick event

Comment: does your problem get fixed?

Comment: Sorry Arash for the late reply. Yes the problem is fixed.

Comment: One more question. I have one edit box and search button. I have to populate the list view below the search button. When I do search for the first time, list is getting populated with the searched results. When I do search again, I am getting an error:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot add header view to list -- setAdapter has already been called.

Comment: @user2740599 : good to hear that and if answer helped you plz mark it as answer! about your problem i can't help you without see at your code and your way of implementation.you can ask another question,somebody or me will help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html).

[Here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablelayout-example/) is an example of how to implement this.